# Span will not go to the next line even after completing length of div

Tags: html, css

I have a few span tags inside a a `div` I made this div a width of `50%`

My problem is that these span tags do not go to the next line when they can no longer fit within that row inside that div

However when I was making an example on JS Fiddle the span tags that could no longer fit within the div went to the next line, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/HQ2Gj/

So I would appreciate help in making the span tags go to the next line when they can no longer fit on my project as well

Thank you in advance

Comment: So figure out what the difference is between your project and the fiddle.

Comment: Or make a fiddle that reproduces the problem. A working fiddle doesn't help much here does it?

Comment: Not sure what is your question. I see 4 hello in line 1 and 5th one in line 2. So what is the problem here?

Comment: Use this css property `{word-wrap:break-word;}`

Comment: What currently happens to the span tags when they don't fit on your project?

Comment: @jack they extend horizontally out of their container, they do not go to the next line, just keep on going

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen besides for using % instead of pixels, there is none.

Comment: For now, you might try setting a background color or something on your containing div, so you can see clearly where the boundaries of that div are - `span` elements should break onto a new line by default, so if they aren't, there's a good chance your container is actually wider than you want it to be.